# Python pandas calculated field function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a function that calculates profit, based on (Revenue-Budget). There are 0 values in Revenue which I do not want in the calculation.

This is what I have so far, but it is throwing up the error '
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
# Function to calcuate the profit only when there is a non 0 value for Budget var1- revenue, var2 - budget, var3 profit
    def profit_cal(var1,var2,var3):
    if(org_data[var1]!=0):
        org_data[var3]=org_data[var1]-org_data[var2]
    else:
        org_data[var3]=0
        return(org_data[var3])

profit_cal('revenue','budget','profit')
```

Comment: your indentation is incorrect. is this truly the way your code looks?

Comment: `org_data['profit']=(org_data['revenue']-org_data['budget']).where(org_data['revenue']==0,0)`

Comment: @Wen , That calculates all profit as 0, even when there are non-null values for revenue and budget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because the if statement is checking if the column as a whole is equal to 0. This will depend on each of the values so it considers it to be 'ambiguous'.

I can think of 3 different ways of achieving the result that you are after.

First, the version that @Wen suggested (he just missed one sign):

```
    def profit_cal1(var1,var2,var3):
        org_data[var3] = (org_data[var1]-org_data[var2]).where(org_data[var2]!=0,0)
```

Now, a version where you iterate throw every row to check if the budget value equals 0:

```
    def profit_cal2(var1,var2,var3):
        org_data[var3] = 0
        for idx,i in enumerate(org_data[var2]):
            if i!=0:
                org_data[var3][idx] = org_data[var1][idx]-org_data[var2][idx]
```

And finally, by calculating the 'profit' for the table as whole and then replacing the values that you don't want with a 0:

```
    def profit_cal3(var1,var2,var3):
        org_data[var3] = org_data[var1] - org_data[var2]
        org_data.loc[org_data[var2]==0,var3] = 0
```

Let's use %timeit to see which one is the most efficient!

```
# Creating a dummy dataframe with zeros in it
org_data = pd.DataFrame()
org_data['revenue'] = np.random.choice(range(100),10000)
org_data['budget'] = np.random.choice(range(100),10000)
```

Results:

```
%timeit profit_cal1('revenue','budget','profit')
```

873 µs ± 4.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

```
%timeit profit_cal2('revenue','budget','profit')
```

1.07 s ± 4.46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
%timeit profit_cal3('revenue','budget','profit')
```

3.41 ms ± 86.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

The first function is the fastest!

Now, it seems like you are trying to make the function flexible (as you are allowing for different columns names. May I suggest making also the name of the dataframe itself an argument of the function?

This would be the updated version of function one with additional flexibility:

```
def profit_cal(X,var1,var2,var3):
    X[var3] = (X[var1]-X[var2]).where(X[var2]!=0,0)
```

Just remember that you have to enter one more argument:

```
profit_cal(org_data,'revenue','budget','profit')
```

Enjoy!